# Which is email authorization more common than other modes of authentication (Social Auth, Phone Auth, Anonymous), especially on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, google-analytics

Are there certain advantages / disadvantages associated with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Social Auth is good one go for that because in that u will get mobile number, email, name, and profile picture if you use Facebook auth and on google auth u will get same almost not mobile number it depends on the user privacy policies but in the phone auth u will only get mobile number and some time user don't want to give a mobile number.